# Haskell Convert List to List of Tuples

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

i have a list like this

```
["peter","1000","michell","2000","kelly","3000"]
```

and i would like to convert to

```
[("peter",1000),("michell", 2000),("kelly",3000)]
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
cnv :: [String] -> [(String, Integer)]
cnv [] = []
cnv (k:v:t) = (k, read v) : cnv t
```

If you want to handle odd-length just add `cnv [x] =` variant before last one

Comment: Can you explain this lines of code cnv (k:v:t) = (k, read v) : cnv t ? 

AFAIK, the k v t is a parameter from list k is the head and v is the tail and cnv t is next element as k. 

Is my understanding correct because previosuly i have function like this. 

convert :: [String] -> [(String, Integer)]
convert [] = []
convert (x:y:xs) = (x, y)convert xs

and why when i add :xs it is not working ? 

Are the k v t is represents a single element in list or whole list ?

Comment: Not quite: in `k:v:t`, `k` is the head, and `v:t` is the tail.  Thus, `k:v:t` puts the first two items of the list into `k` and `v` and the remaining tail in `t`.  Your code has two obvious problems: (a) `(x,y)` has type `(String,String)`, not `(String,Integer)`; and (b) there's no colon before `convert xs`.  (You can't just do `:xs`, because you need `[(String,Integer)]` but `xs` has type `[String]`.)  Also, a formatting tip: indent lines with four blank spaces to get code blocks (or select your code and click the "101010" button), and surround code snippets with backticks (\`...code...\`).

Comment: (x:xs) That means x is the head and remaining element is tail for xs. 

Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @Antal S-Z is right. `(k:v:t)` equivalent to `(k:(v:t))` because of declaration `infixr 5 :` in [`GHC.Types`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ghc-prim/0.1.0.0/doc/html/src/GHC-Types.html) (as well `data [] a = [] | a : [a]` will tell you about meaning of `(v:t)` or `[]`).

Comment: (or select your code and click the "101010" button), and surround code snippets with backticks (`...code...`). 

Any example. How to do that manually ? 

I don't understand what you say here. 

(k:v:t) equivalent to (k:(v:t)) because of declaration infixr 5 : in GHC.Types (as well data [] a = [] | a : [a] will tell you about meaning of (v:t) or [])

Comment: The `infixr 5 :` statement says that `:` groups to the right with precedence 5.  In other words, `w:x:y:z` is `w:(x:(y:z))`, not `((w:x):y):z`.  The `5` tells you where it falls in the precedence chain; for instance, since `*` comes before `+`, `*` has precedence 7 whereas `+` has precedence 6.  What the `data [] a = [] | a : [a]` declaration tells you is the definition of `:` and `[]`; that is, that they construct parts of lists, etc.  As for formatting: just type \`before your code, and \` after it.  Read [the editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more.

Answer (score 8):

[ony's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067048/haskell-convert-list-to-list-of-tuples/3067081#3067081) is a bit shorter, but here's a non-recursive version using `splitEvery` from the very handy [`split` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.1/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html):

```
cnv = map (\[name, amount] -> (name, read amount :: Int)) . splitEvery 2
```

The steps here are somewhat clearer (for me, at least) than in the recursive version.

Comment: This is definitely more natural.  The split library doesn't get enough love.  It's too bad, since it's incredibly useful.

Comment: Note that `splitEvery` appears to be deprecated now; use [`chunksOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly for a task like this I find it convenient to have a `stride` function to take every n-th element from the list:

```
stride _ [] = []
stride n (x:xs) = x : stride n (drop (n-1) xs)
```

It can be used to convert a list to pairs:

```
toPairs xs = zip (stride 2 xs) (stride 2 (drop 1 xs))
```

An example (note that the last element may be thrown away if it doesn't have pair):

```
ghci> stride 2 [1..5]
[1,3,5]
ghci> toPairs [1..7]
[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```

It can be even easily extended to triplets or longer tuples:

```
toTriplets xs = zip3 as bs cs
  where as = stride 3 xs
        bs = stride 3 $ drop 1 xs
        cs = stride 3 $ drop 2 xs
```

To perform conversion from `String` to integer in your example, you can map `read` function over the second stride:

```
let lst = ["peter","1000","michell","2000","kelly","3000"] in
zip (stride 2 lst) (map read . stride 2 . drop 1 $ lst) :: [(String,Int)]
```

which gives:

```
[("peter",1000),("michell",2000),("kelly",3000)]
```