# Haskell function that goes through each pair in list and returns a list with size smaller than original by 1

Tags: haskell

Suppose we have list [1,2,3,4].
I want to take every pair of consecutive elements (i.e. (1,2),(2,3),(3,4)), apply them to some function, and return list which consist of results of this function.
I don't quite understand, how to do this on haskell, since we don't actually have loops and arrays here.

Comment: Once you have the list of pairs, you would just `map` the function over the list. To get the pair though, I believe Haskell has a `partition` function that does what you want. Also, Haskell *does* have looping technically, just not formal looping language constructs. Most things are achieved by either recursion, or some abstraction that uses recursion (like `map`).

Comment: Hint: use `zipWith`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Out of curiosity, do you get phone alerts or something for the `[Haskell]` tag? Your response time is typically very quick for Haskell questions.

Comment: Can't you just do this with `zip`, nevermind `zipWith`? If your list is `lst`, then `zip (init lst) (tail lst)` should do it, no? [Obviously you'll have to take care if your list might be empty.]

Comment: @Carcigenicate: well you can open the newest questions in a tab. If you pin it, some browsers, like Firefox, give a notification if the title changes, that's all :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ahh. I was expecting something complicated using email notifications or something. I want to get something set up for [Clojure]. Thanks. Chrome might allow for the same notifications if I look through the settings.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks! I missed `map` function. And for parting initial list into list of pairs, I used this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067048/haskell-convert-list-to-list-of-tuples

Answer (score 4):

Here are some ways you could try to solve this. The first step will be to get the pairs and the second will be applying the function to the pairs. One way to do the first step is with a recursive function. Now in Haskell lists are made using `[]` and `:`, with `[1,2,3]` being syntactic sugar for `1:(2:(3:[]))`. So let us write our function:

```
window [] = []
window [a] = []
window [a,b] = [(a,b)]
window (a:b:r) = (a,b):window (b:r)
```

Another way we could do this is with the function `zip`. Recall that this takes two lists, pairs up their elements, and ends the list when either input ends.

```
window [] = []
window xs = zip xs (tail xs)
```

The second step is to apply our function to the pairs. We can do this with `map (uncurry f)`. All together:

```
onWindow f = map (uncurry f) . window
```

Answer (score 2):

There's several approaches that could work here.

You could use recursion:

```
mapCons :: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
-- input has at least two elements
mapCons f (a0:a1:as) =
  -- use them to compute the head of the output
  f a0 a1 :
  -- reuse the second element to compute the tail of the output
  mapCons f (a1:as)
-- input has less than two elements, so output is the empty list
mapCons _ _ = []
```

Alternately, `zip` converts a pair of lists into a list of pairs:

```
λ zip [1..10] ['a'..'z']
[(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d'),(5,'e'),(6,'f'),(7,'g'),(8,'h'),(9,'i'),(10,'j')]
```

This gives a way to generate all the consecutive pairs in a list by zipping a list with its own tail:

```
λ zip [1..10] ['a'..'z']
[(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d'),(5,'e'),(6,'f'),(7,'g'),(8,'h'),(9,'i'),(10,'j')]
```

You could then use `map` to run your function on each pair in the list

```
λ map (\(a,b) -> 10*a + b) $ zip [0..9] (tail [0..9])
[1,12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89]
```

This is a common enough pattern that there's a function that combines `map` and `zip`: `zipWith`:

```
λ :t zipWith
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
λ zipWith (\a b -> 10*a + b) [0..9] (tail [0..9])
[1,12,23,34,45,56,67,78,89]
```

Comment: You can shorten this even more: `(zipWith f <*> tail) [0..9]`.